# Android: Async Thread Issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have an app that is loading data from text files and storing the data from each file into a separate `ArrayList`. I was told to load the data on an async thread even though my app does not crash loading it all from the onCreate method (it just takes approx 12 seconds to load all of the data from the text files into the ArrayLists).

I have attempted to set up an async thread, but I have run into an issue. I am brand new to async threads, so I do not know/yet fully understand all of the details (I am trying to piece info together from different sources). Here is the relevent code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);

    new loadData().execute();

    arrayListElement = ArrayList1.get(0);

}

private class loadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        populateArrayLists();
        return null;
    }

    /*protected void onProgressUpdate() {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {

    }*/

}
```

I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException (invalid index 0, size is 0) at the last statement in the onCreate method.

All I want to do is load the data on a separate thread because even though my app does not crash, I was told I should do it. The UI thread should handle all of the rest. The app was working fine until I added the async thread code.

How my files are read can be seen here:
[Android: Asynch Thread Needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719157/android-asynch-thread-needed)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello again! Aside from the fixes suggested below, and after you get this working, you may run into another problem when you want to dismiss your progress dialog in `onPostExecute`, if the user rotates the screen or something similar reloads your Activity. Since this is waiting, the user may navigate away and trigger a reload. See [this article](http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/proper-use-of-asynctask/). That's why I suggested the Loader API, it brings less trouble.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Ok, I know that you said it had been awhile since you had worked with it, but do you think you could put something together that would load the files like you saw? I am just looking to load the 15 files each to their own ArrayList. The onClick method will handle everything else. I will look at the Loader API and try to find some examples later today in addition to seeing if I can get the async method working (provided by LuxuryMode). [I am in college teaching myself this, so I work on it in my free time. :) ]

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn All I have been able to find so far are overly complicated examples that I do not understand and ones for loading databases (which I also do not understand). :| I cannot find an example anywhere for loaders for reading from files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning null from doInBackground, so of course this all fails. Use the AsyncTask for what it's meant to do. To get it to work correctly, you need to correctly define your AsyncTask with the appropriate type paramaters.

Instead of making populateArrayLists have side effects of updating some other field, have a method like:

```
void List<Foo> getListOfFoo() {
  ArrayList<Foo> listOfFoos = getTheListSomehow();
  return listOfFoos;
}
```

For example:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {


        public void doSomething(List<String> stringList) {
           //do something here

        }

        class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                ArrayList<String> listOfStrings = getListOfStrings();
                return listOfStrings;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
                super.onPostExecute(strings);
                doSomething(strings);
            }

            private List<String> getListOfStrings() {
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
                //This is where you'd actually perform your expensive operation
  BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                "text1.txt")));
        String text;
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringList.add(text);
        }                           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close(); // stop reading
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
                return stringList;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me try this...It will take a little bit of time for me to adapt/make the necessary changes to fit my code...

Comment: It is proving a little more difficult than I thought because I have global ArrayLists and in my populateArrayLists() method, I read in all the files one after another and fill all of the ArrayLists. (See my linked question.)

Comment: @lord_sneed no problem. see my edit. just do that work in your getListOfStrings method

Comment: I am only using the async thread to load the data from the files. After that, everything is done from the onClick method. There are 15 ArrayLists, so does that affect the parameter of the onPostExecute and the return statement of the doInBackground?

Comment: Your edit only addresses one of the files, there are 14 more :) My populateArrayLists did all 15 (after it did "text1.txt" -> ArrayList1, then it did "text2.txt" -> ArrayList2, .. and so on). The 15 ArrayLists are global and the method had a return type of `void`.

Comment: Do you have any further ideas as to how to read all 15 files into 15 ArrayLists and not just one?

Comment: Nevermind. Rather than having 15 separate files, I will have it load one large file -> one ArrayList, then I will have a method to do regex to separate the contents into their separate ArrayLists. Thank you for your time and efforts and for something that works. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask is not yet done running, that's why `arrayListElement = ArrayList1.get(0);` is having an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try This

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);

    new loadData().execute();
}

private class loadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        populateArrayLists();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        arrayListElement = ArrayList1.get(0);
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have other stuff in the onCreate method (buttons, etc.) Should the call to this be the last thing then? From what I understand from the documentation, the onPostExecute is what is executed after the doInBackground, but does it return back to the onCreate? Or would it then be done with the onCreate and move on to the user interaction methods (such as onClick)?

Comment: Also I am getting a warning that onPostExecute is never used locally if I follow your answer.

Comment: **AsyncTask** is a parallel process. So if the **AsyncTask** is executed, it will have it's own process, onCreate will not wait it to finish the **AsyncTask**, onCreate will continue the line of codes underneath the `new loadData().execute();`

Comment: Hmmm why this answer get upvotes? This wont work. Try @LuxuryMode answer instead!

Comment: Ok...after implementation another error came up. The spinner came up, but it basically ran in an infinite loop until it ran out of memory. This did not happen without the async thread code where it loaded everything just fine.

Comment: @load_sneed add `dialog.dismiss()` to the `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: @Ramyle That does not fix it..same problem.

Comment: @LazyNinja You are back on my questions! :)

Comment: @lord_sneed I tested the asynctask and updated my answer. Update your onPostExecute, the spinner should dismiss now.

Comment: @Ramyle It does not. I am not looking for something that will go away after some time after you click and/or it runs out of memory. Not only that, but my TextView to display element 0 does not show.

Comment: @lord_sneed I tested the asynctask with the spinner, it doesn't give me any errors. Try to put a `Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPost");` in the onPost if it's executing it, if not there's a problem in your `populateArrayLists();`

Comment: @Ramyle There is nothing wrong with my method to populate all of the ArrayLists. The method works just fine without the async thread code. It was a suggestion that I put the reading of the files on a different thread, which is why I am doing it. I do not think you are testing it properly. If I click outside of the spinner dialog box, yes it goes away, but nothing works. If I do nothing, it just sits there in a seemingly infinite loop. If you look at my linked question, you will see how I read in all of the files/populate all of the ArrayLists.